# Python - SyntaxError and IndentationError

Tags: python, interpreter, python-2.6

I know that python is an interpreter language and it means that it interprets the code at run time, so why is that code gives me IndentationError?

```
def function(x):
    if x:
```

Does it check all the code before running it?

Comment: What comes after the if?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, functions are objects.

You get an error immediately because the Python interpreter wasn't able to construct a function object from your function definition due to improper syntax. In this case not having an indented block after your if statement.

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Creating a function instance happens before calling a function.

```
>>> def errorOnCall(x):
...     return x / 0
... 
>>> print errorOnCall
<function errorOnCall at 0x7f249aaef578>
```

Function object created due to no syntax error, but the function will raise an error when we invoke it.

```
>>> errorOnCall(42)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in errorOnCall
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

Now an error is thrown as soon as we invoke this function.

```
>>> def errorOnDefinition(x):
...     if x:
... 
  File "<stdin>", line 3

    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

This error is thrown when we finish defining our function, but before we invoke it. The interpreter wasn't able to create a function instance from this invalid definition.

Answer (score 1):

When Python loads a module, the source code is run through the Python interpreter and "compiled" into an internal data structure.  Therefore, errors that violate the rules of Python syntax are caught on load.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get any indentation error

```
 def function(x):
   if x:
       print x
```

I am new to python can you explain how you get this error ??? 
As i tried the ipython didn't allow me to end line without typing any statement.so i added "print x " in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Because indentation is an element of Python syntax, so it's checked during syntax analysis.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have something following the "if x:" statement.  The following would be the least you would need to avoid an error.

```
    def function(x):
        if x:
            pass
```

Comment: I know that, I just didn't understand how can it be because I didn't call the function

Comment: I was a little quick on the answer, missed the question at the end.  Yes, code is checked when compiled.  As someone stated below, syntax errors will be caught on load.